# Split for special array (query) by character + character in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Im using simple split to array function in js

```
const qwery = username.split('');
```

& it's splitting all name by characters with white spaces.
For exmaple - Dohn Joe - [D, o, h, n, , J, o, e]
How can i make this?
[D, Do, Doh, Dohn, DohnJ, DohnJo, DohnJoe] (also without spacing) ?

Comment: What you're describing isn't a split, what made you reach for the `split` function? It won't repeat string contents. I'm 99% sure you'll need a loop for this. Have you tried one?

Comment: No, im noob in js:( if you can - please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` doesn't do what you want, you probably want a simple loop:

```js
const username = 'Dohn Joe';
const qwery = [];
for (let i = 0; i < username.length; ++i) {
    qwery[i] = username.substring(0, i + 1).replace(/\s/g, "");
}
console.log(qwery);
```

Some notes:

- `username.substring(0, i + 1)` gives you the text of the string from the beginning (index 0) up to index `i + 1` (but not including it).
- `qwery[i] =` extends the array if necessary and assigns to the entry at index `i`
- `.replace(/\s/g, "")` removes any whitespace in the substring we're adding to the array